# What is the word for the last two digits of a number?

Tags: definition

I'm working on a script to translate numbers to words. (e.g. 111 to "one hundred and eleven".

It's very easy to create this for the English language since it has very clear rules.

At this moment I have a function that converts the last two digits of a number to their respective words.

So 0 to "zero", 1 to "one", 10 to "ten", 21 to "twenty-one", etc...

I know that the least significant number is called a "unit" and the second least significant numbers are called the "tens", but what is the name for all numbers ranging from 0 to 99.

My goal is to change the current function name, which is `numberUnder100ToWords`, to something more meaningful.

Comment: There isn't one. Your current descriptor is perfectly clear so I would recommend using that.

Comment: I would have called it the congruence modulo $100$.